# Authorization has been denied for this request even when user is authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Suddenly, this error started happening. The web api method is this:

```
    // POST api/Account/Logout
    [Route("Logout")]
    public IHttpActionResult Logout()
    {
        Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        return Ok();
    }
```

That method is inside AccountController which has [Authorize] attribute.

When I just logged in and I see a page that also has [Authorize], I press a button that allows me to log out. Tha log out button calls the Web Api using Ajax.

Let me tell you also that this worked before.... suddenly it stopped working.

I have added this code in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
        var config = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();
        app.UseWebApi(config);
```

But it did not work either. I added that line just in case, because as I have old you, this worked before, without that line.

Any help on this, please?

Also please, don't suggest to remove [Authorize] attibute, as I have seen in other answeres here. Web Api's have to be called being authenticated.

EDIT: this is the call in Ajax:

```
self.logout = function () {
    // Log out from the cookie based logon.
    var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
    var headers = {};
    if (token) {
        headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/Logout',
        headers: headers
    }).done(function (data) {
        // Successfully logged out. Delete the token.
        self.user('');
        sessionStorage.removeItem(tokenKey);

        location.href = '/';
    }).fail(showError);
}
```

Comment: *"Tha log out button calls the Web Api using Ajax"*: how are the credentials/token/auth_cookies being passed to the controller?

Comment: @Stefan I have removed cookies in browser and it started working again. /api/Account/Logout started working, but the problem is that suddenly, it stops working. I have edited the question to show you how the ajax call is made.

Comment: Ah, bearer; changes a big that the token has expired on your last try. Make sure you refresh it according to the identity provider.